# There is the problem of putting back and drawing 5 different cards.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Each time a student attends a lecture, the organizer gives out one card at random. The card is written with one of the five different letters from A to E. **How many lectures does a student need to attend on average to collect all the five different cards?**

I think this is a problem of how many times a card is successfully collected, so the probability of success on the n-th time is obey geometrical distributed. Suppose X is the i-th event that successfully gets the "A" card. $p(X=j)=(\frac{4}{5})^{j-1}*\frac{1}{5}$. How can I continue to solve this problem?

Comment: This problem is known as the [Coupon Collector's Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n$ different cards, the answer is $n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$.

The key insight is to define random variables $X_k$ as the number of lectures you need to attend *after* you obtained your $(k-1)$-th card, until the lecture in which you receive the $k$-th distinct card. So $X_k\sim\operatorname{Geo}\left(\frac{n-k+1}{n}\right)$.

Then we can just apply linearity of expectation:
$$\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right]=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb E[X_k]=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n-k+1}=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.$$